# Can't install Nvidia Driver fo 4090

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 22.04

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu 22.04 on my new Desktop with 4090. I keep getting an error when trying install latest driver. Below screenshot is what I get repeatedly.

[image]

Comment: The progress bar shows you are in the middle of applying changes.  Which driver were you selecting?  Might try the Ubuntu 23.04  with the 6.2 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to download from terminal ?

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
reboot
```

After reboot you can confirm installation with:

```
nvidia-smi
```